# C++ Logical constancy and a returning by value from a const method

Tags: c++, constants

There's a class that exposes some of its functionallity and data via another connected class' object returned by value.
For example a container type that returns iterators class through begin() and end() methods. It returns iterator by value so

```
iterator begin();
const iterator begin() const;
```

won't work and we need two separate classes iterator and const_iterator but then the principle of code reusing is being violated as we need to implement similar functionality in both classes.

Are there any workarounds? How to find a compromise between code reuse and reserving a constancy?

Comment: Your code is just a variation on the confusion between `T * const` and `T const *`. They're not the same, and one can't be substituted for the other.

Comment: No it's a whole different theme. It's about a logical constancy of user defined types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I have never seen it done any other way than creating `const`  and non-const versions of functions and classes.